# Same calculations on multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI desktop and I am trying to conceptually understand the best way to tackle this problem. So I have a table that looks like this:

| Index | FIFO2_1 | FIFO2_2 | FIFO2_3 | FIFO2_4 | FIFO2_5 | FIFO2_6 | FIFO2_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.097 | 0.096 | 0.101 | 0.096 | 0.191 | 0.187 | 0.098 |
| 1 | 0.096 | 0.094 | 0.099 | 0.094 | 0.188 | 0.184 | 0.096 |
| 2 | 0.094 | 0.093 | 0.098 | 0.093 | 0.185 | 0.182 | 0.095 |
| 3 | 0.093 | 0.092 | 0.097 | 0.092 | 0.184 | 0.180 | 0.094 |
| 4 | 0.093 | 0.091 | 0.096 | 0.091 | 0.182 | 0.179 | 0.094 |
| 5 | 0.092 | 0.090 | 0.095 | 0.091 | 0.181 | 0.178 | 0.093 |
| 6 | 0.091 | 0.090 | 0.095 | 0.090 | 0.179 | 0.177 | 0.092 |
| 7 | 0.091 | 0.089 | 0.094 | 0.090 | 0.178 | 0.176 | 0.092 |
| 8 | 0.090 | 0.088 | 0.094 | 0.089 | 0.177 | 0.175 | 0.091 |
| 9 | 0.089 | 0.088 | 0.093 | 0.089 | 0.176 | 0.174 | 0.091 |
| 10 | 0.089 | 0.087 | 0.092 | 0.088 | 0.175 | 0.173 | 0.091 |
| 11 | 0.088 | 0.087 | 0.092 | 0.088 | 0.174 | 0.173 | 0.090 |
| 12 | 0.088 | 0.086 | 0.091 | 0.087 | 0.173 | 0.172 | 0.090 |
| 13 | 0.088 | 0.086 | 0.091 | 0.087 | 0.172 | 0.171 | 0.089 |
| 14 | 0.087 | 0.086 | 0.091 | 0.086 | 0.171 | 0.171 | 0.089 |
| 15 | 0.087 | 0.085 | 0.090 | 0.086 | 0.170 | 0.170 | 0.089 |
| 16 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.126 | 0.064 |
| 17 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.127 | 0.064 |
| 18 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.126 | 0.064 |
| 19 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.126 | 0.064 |
| 20 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.127 | 0.064 |
| 21 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.126 | 0.064 |
| 22 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.126 | 0.064 |
| 23 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.126 | 0.064 |
| 24 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.126 | 0.064 |
| 25 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.126 | 0.064 |
| 26 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.126 | 0.064 |
| 27 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.126 | 0.064 |
| 28 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.126 | 0.064 |
| 29 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.126 | 0.064 |
| 30 | 0.063 | 0.063 | 0.066 | 0.063 | 0.125 | 0.126 | 0.064 |

I want to perform operations that will done on each one of the seven columns. For example, one of the steps I want to perform is taking the average for rows 15-20 for every columns, so it will AVG1, AVG2,....AVG7. Then I will subtract from the average every value in the corresponding column.
So for FIFO2_1, if average is AVG1 then the formula will be AVG - Xi (where i ranges from 0-30).

Next, I will search for the index of the highest value for every column, so it will be MAX1, MAX2,..., MAX7. Then I will take the index and get the average of the last 10 points, this again for every column. So you can see it's a sequential process and I am not sure what will be the best way to preform it. It's the same process for every column.

What I did until now is create a measure for every column and then divide the

```
AverageBetween400and440 = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('Table'[FIFO_1_1]),
    'Table'[Index] >= 15 && 'Table'[Index] <= 20
)
```

```
transformed_FIFI2_1 = 
VAR X= [AverageBetween400and440]
RETURN CALCULATE(X- SUM(Table[FIFO_1_1]))
```

My plan is to replicate this for every columns but honestly this is not efficient a all and I don't even know how to perform the next steps. Is there a way to automate the process for all the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with columns is hard in this way, whereas working in rows is much easier.

In PowerQuery, look to unpivot your table. Right-click on the `Index` column header, and select `Unpivot Other Columns`. In the formula bar for that step, feel free to rename `Attribute` to another name like `FIFO2`.

```
= Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Index"}, "FIFO2", "Value")
```

You should then have a table structure like this:

| Index | FIFO2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | FIFO2_1 | 0.097 |
| 0 | FIFO2_2 | 0.096 |
| 0 | FIFO2_3 | 0.101 |
| 0 | FIFO2_4 | 0.096 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 30 | FIFO2_6 | 0.126 |
| 30 | FIFO2_7 | 0.064 |

Now you can have measures created like the following:

```
AverageBetween400and440 = 
  CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('Table'[Value]),
    'Table'[Index] >= 15 && 'Table'[Index] <= 20
  )


transformed_FIFI2 =  [AverageBetween400and440] - SUM('Table'[Value])


Avg Last 10 Max = 
  var maxV = MAX('Table'[Value])
  var maxI = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Index]), 'Table'[Value] = maxV)  // change MAX to MIN if you want to get the first index of max value (incase there is a tie)
  RETURN
    CALCULATE(
      AVERAGE('Table'[Value]),
      'Table'[Index] > maxI - 10 && 'Table'[Index] <= maxI // adjust as needed
    )
```

The above measures will work so long as you have `'Table'[FIFO2]` in the visual, otherwise they will calculate regardless of the `FIFO2`.

[image]

Comment: Hey Sam, this is working perfectly but there is an issue with the the measure Avg Last 10 Max. So the basically the max will be taken from the transformed_FIFI2 and then the average is also taken from the transformed_FIFI2. I edited it this say but it still not working: 


Avg Last 10 Max =
 var x = [transformed_FIFI2 ] 
 var maxV = MAX(x) 
 var maxI = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Index]), 'Table'[transformed_FIFI2] = maxV) RETURN AVERAGE( x, 'Table'[Index] > maxI - 10 && 'Table'[Index] <= maxI // adjust as needed )

Comment: `[AverageBetween400and440]` will be constant, and `[transformed_FIFI]` will also be constant - ie both will have the same value regardless of the Index within their respective `FIFO2` value (column). so I don't understand why you need to take the max and then the avg of these.

Comment: I got it to work just now, maybe looking to what I did what make it more clear to you:
TOP Transform Values = TOPN(1, VALUES('Table_1'[Index]), [transformed_FIFI], DESC)

Avg Last 10 Max = 
  var maxV = [TOP Transform Values]
  RETURN
    CALCULATE(
      AVERAGEX(VALUES(Table[Index]),
      [transformed_FIFI],
      'Table'[Index] >= (maxV - 10) && 'Table'[Index] <= maxV , ALLEXCEPT(Table,Table[FIFO2])
    )

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to add them in code format in the comment. It's a sequential process, after I take the max of transformed_FIFI2, I will then look for the last 10 points before the max and and take their average. It's all based on transformed_FIFI2. Later I will divide transformed_FIFI2 by the average I got. It's the data manipulation process I need. THANKS A LOT for directing me to pivoting the table, it changed how I see the problem. I am used to python and this is just painful to me.

Comment: I'm glad you resolved it. I'm still not understanding how/why `transformed_FIFI` varies per `Index`.